# Rails 3: Set a route as 'get'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a route as:

`match 'api/v1/:id/:format/:date/(:type)', :controller => "xpto", :action => "api_xpto"`

The goal is to make it as a GET request from the outside. However, the route is not being set as a GET.

How can I make it a GET?

Answer (score 1):

Change **match** to **get**:

```
get 'api/v1/:id/:format/:date/(:type)', :controller => "xpto", :action => "api_xpto"
```

Or add :via option

```
match 'api/v1/:id/:format/:date/(:type)', :controller => "xpto", :action => "api_xpto", :via => :get
```

Comment: Actually, `:as` is used for naming routes. The correct option for this is `:via => :get`

Comment: Thanks, wrote too quick. Edited.